# Staff line and space numbering in Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

Is is needed to numbering the lines and spaces of staff, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 


\begin{document}
The lines of the staff are numbered from bottom to top.

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nostartrule
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% i
    \NOTEs\wh{*****egikm}\en
    \endpiece
 \end{music}
 
The spaces between the lines are also numbered from bottom to top.

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nostartrule
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% i
    \NOTEs\wh{*****fhjl}\en
    \endpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The expected output is as follow (note that is needed to include the numbering for lines and spaces):
[image: expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This edited is a solution with two ways of using `\tabfnt`, which you can find in the manual. It has a little white square around the number. Otherwise you will have to look for another font available or define one yourself.
Be aware that i changed `\endpiece` into `\zendpiece` to eliminate the bar at the end.
To have the line fit into your width, you must reduce the `\NOTEs` to `\NOtes` resp. `\NOTes`.

```
  \documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{circledtext}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 


\begin{document}
The lines of the staff are numbered from bottom to top.

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}%
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nostartrule
   \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% i
    \NOtes\hsk\tab{5}{1}\tab{4}{2}\tab{3}{3}\tab{2}{4}\tab{1}{5}\wh{egikm}\en% using standard tab command, which works like this only for lines
    \zendpiece
 \end{music}
 
The spaces between the lines are also numbered from bottom to top.

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nostartrule
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
\tabfnt % using tabfnt for all test or numbers, to not do so for every charnote individually
    \startpiece%
    \NOTes\hsk\charnote e{1}\charnote g{2}\charnote i{\tabfnt 3}\charnote k{\tabfnt 4}\wh{fhjl}\en
    \zendpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabfnt]

Comment: Hi Peters, the target is to include numbering with square white background color as shown in the expected picture. Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{circledtext}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 


\begin{document}
The lines of the staff are numbered from bottom to top.

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 7pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}%
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nostartrule
   \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% i
    \NOtes\hsk\tab{5}{\A 1}\tab{4}{\A 2}\tab{3}{\A 3}\tab{2}{\A 4}\tab{1}{\A 5}\wh{egikm}\en% using standard tab command, which works like this only for lines
    \zendpiece
 \end{music}
 
The spaces between the lines are also numbered from bottom to top.

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 7pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nostartrule
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
\tabfnt % using tabfnt for all test or numbers, to not do so for every charnote individually
    \startpiece%
    \NOTes\hsk\charnote e{\tabfnt \A 1}\charnote g{\A 2}\charnote i{\tabfnt \A 3}\charnote k{\tabfnt \A 4}\wh{fhjl}\en
    \zendpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

[image: solved]